# ESP32 and Linux module integration

Tags: esp32, linux

I'm an IT Engineer, I code, but I have a little skills with electronics. I'm making my first project and I need your help to not mess my departure :)
I would like to start my prototype and I think ESP32-S3 is good for my need, my device it's a kind of access control system and here is a quick scheme to explain the functioning.

[image]

My question is about the possibility to add the Linux module for database checking (and possible other scripts), do you think this could be the best solution to do that? (For me as a computer scientist this is the easiest way.) However, if I go with this architecture I must find a solution to integrate/communicate the ESP32-S3 and Linux module? Do you have an idea for a Linux module that you can suggest the simplest/cheapest one?

The second part of my question is about the possibility to install MicroPython Web Server into ESP32, it will work probably, but is it also efficient/stable?

Comment: what is a linux module? ... software or hardware?

Comment: @jsotola Hardware which I want to put it in the same board than Esp32

Comment: It would be much easier if you told us what your goal is. Here I don’t understand why you would need both a Linux device and an ESP32. Do you expect the two to be in separate devices or is it just one device? If just one, why do you need? If separate devices, how far apart? Can you run wires between the two? Or use WiFi? As it stands your question is way to broad, there are tons of different ways to make a Linux device and and ESP32 device talk to each other (serial, Ethernet, WiFi, BLE at least).

Comment: shopping questions are off topic here ... there is a stackexchange site that deals with a tiny linux computer ... starts with the letter `R`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really too few specifics given about your situation, but anyway:

First let's get simple things out of the way. I may be wrong, but I get a feeling that you want to run 'Linux module' on ESP32 hardware. 'Linux module' has to be a separate hardware piece.

Do you need it at all? If the whole purpose is to act like a connection between ESP32 and a database (which?) then you might actually not need it. On a diagram your 'database' looks like some remote server on a local network, in which case you might be able to directly access it from ESP with Http requests.

If you still need 'Linux module' for some reason, you need to specify which hardware it will be. Most likely you will be able to use UART to send data to/from ESP32.

As for web-server on ESP32 it is possible and MicroPython is not needed for that. But I don't understand why you would want it. Web server is needed if you want to host some local web page or respond to Http requests. You don't need a web server to simply send Http requests to database.

Have you considered an alternative solution to keep **everything** on ESP32? You can keep a small kind-of-database on its EEPROM. Hard to say without your specific requirements though.

Comment: Thanks a lot @floppydisk, It's this kind of answer which we are looking by coming at stackexchange ! I'll try to answer to your questions :

Comment: - No I want to get them in separate hardware piece, in the same breadboard but they must communicate (How ? It's a part of my question) 
- Yes, the database it's a postgresql in a remote computer. 
- The task #3 is a http POST request sent to Linux server, I thought on a webserver also for the device administration interface.

Comment: - Yes, it would really suit me to simplify the circuit and keep only the esp32. Given my level in electronics, I'm not very sure if we can implement a kind of replication of the database (or at least the necessary view) in the EEPROM only with the ESP32, what do you think ?

Comment: What kind of data you need to store and how would you like to modify it? These are the questions that define your choice of storage system. I assume the data is simply pairs of RFID_id - access (true or false). If you don't need to modify in on the fly, you don't even need EEPROM then. A const array included in the firmware code will do. You'll need to re-flash for each access change.
If you need to modify it at runtime, there's libraries to use EEPROM like a key-value storage or LittleFS overlay where you can store JSON files. Or you can make up your own binary format and use EEPROM directly

Comment: it's info like rfid_id, name, datestamps ... and yes I want to modify it, so I think I need to EEPROM to store a local tiny database, but another newbie question, my concern is to synchronize this database with the main database, ESP32 can do that with background processes (multitasking) like an conventional OS ?

Comment: No, there's no real 'background' processes and there's nothing happening automatically. Everything has to be done explicitly by your code. Check out this [library](https://github.com/contrem/arduino-timer) - it's pretty simple and helps greatly with timing stuff and running 'tasks' asynchronously. Internally it relies on millis() function to measure time so it will work just as well on ESP32 as on Arduino.

Comment: Thank you a lot @floppydisk